# MissingMemberException was unhandled EntitySet X object has no attribute Y

Tags: c#, python, linq, ironpython

*Update* 
I think the issue may be that I have my associations set up wrong....some tables are one to one and I have them as one to many...

Im writing a reports program using ironpython C# and linq2sql. The error occurs in the report python file at this code:

```
#Evaluation Comment Workflow Records
doc.EvaluationCommentworkflowRecords = [];
if (doc.crRecord.V_SOS_CR_EVAL and doc.crRecord.V_SOS_CR_EVAL.V_SOS_WFDSTs.Count > 0):
    doc.EvaluationCommentworkflowRecords = doc.crRecord.V_SOS_CR_EVAL.V_SOS_WFDSTs.Where(lambda     p: p.DOCTYPE and 
                                                                                 p.DOCTYPE == (doc.evalDocType) and
                                                                                 p.ST_DATE).OrderBy(lambda p: p.ST_DATE).ToList()
#End Evaluation Comment Workflow Records
return doc
```

The error message I get says EntitySet[V_SOS_CR_EVAL] object has no attribute V_SOS_WFDSTs.

But i make the connection in linq2sql with an association and in the dataprovider class:

```
        //evaluation and subs
        loadOptions.LoadWith<V_SOS_CR>(p => p.V_SOS_CR_EVAL);
        loadOptions.LoadWith<V_SOS_CR_EVAL>(p => p.SOS_ATTs);
        loadOptions.LoadWith<V_SOS_CR_EVAL>(p => p.V_SOS_WFDSTs);
```

and this is the DBML designer.cs file below:

```
        public V_SOS_CR_EVAL()
    {
        this._SOS_ATTs = new EntitySet<SOS_ATT>(new Action<SOS_ATT>(this.attach_SOS_ATTs), new Action<SOS_ATT>(this.detach_SOS_ATTs));
        this._V_SOS_WFDSTs = new EntitySet<V_SOS_WFDST>(new Action<V_SOS_WFDST>(this.attach_V_SOS_WFDSTs), new Action<V_SOS_WFDST>(this.detach_V_SOS_WFDSTs));
        this._V_SOS_CR = default(EntityRef<V_SOS_CR>);
        OnCreated();
    }
```

then farther down in the code it has:

```
        public V_SOS_WFDST()
    {
        this._V_SOS_CR = default(EntityRef<V_SOS_CR>);
        this._V_SOS_CR_MRULE = default(EntityRef<V_SOS_CR_MRULE>);
        this._V_SOS_CR_OPERABILITY = default(EntityRef<V_SOS_CR_OPERABILITY>);
        this._V_SOS_CR_REPORTABILITY = default(EntityRef<V_SOS_CR_REPORTABILITY>);
        this._V_SOS_CR_EVAL = default(EntityRef<V_SOS_CR_EVAL>);
        this._V_SOS_CR_ACTION = default(EntityRef<V_SOS_CR_ACTION>);
        OnCreated();
    }
```

If anyone can think of how to fix this error please let me know!

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Associations with the tables. I had many set to one to many when they should have been one to one...